# pigpio Not allowing simultaneous waveforms on separate GPIOs

Tags: pi-3, python-3, pigpio, step-motor

I am trying to send a set of pulses equally spaced to 4 stepper motors drivers (on different GPIOs) at the same time.

These pulses I am wanting to be around 10 microseconds in width so more precise timing than time.sleep can offer.

I have tried to use the pigpio library to accomplish this.

I have not used the built in PWM mode as I am wanting to send a certain number of pulses. (I realise that you could turn the PWM on and off in a specified time to get a specified number of pulses but am wanting to avoid this)

I thought the wave_create function would work well but I have multiple issues:

1st: The pulses are twice as long as I set them (I have fudged the code to mask this, but this may be me not understanding the commands)

2nd: Previously setup waveforms are being cancelled when I start another one

Here is a zoom-in on a single pulse (the delay in the pigpio.pulse is set to 50 microseconds yet on the scope it is 100 microseconds)

[image: This shows how the pulsewidth is twice the delay I specified]

Here is a simplified section of my code that replicates the error I was having with the waveforms being cancelled

```
import pigpio

motorStepPins = (18, 23, 24, 25)        # These are the GPIO addresses for the motor wires
motorDirectionPins = (4, 17, 27, 22)
motorEnablePins = (5, 6, 13, 26)

numberOfSteps = (100, 50, 20, 10)       # This is the number of steps that each motor will advance
motorNumbers = (0, 1, 2, 3)             

pulseWidth = 100                        # The pulsewidth in microseconds
cycleTime = 20                          # time that the number of steps needs to be completed in

motors = pigpio.pi()                    # This initiates pigpio
for motorPin in motorStepPins:          # defines the mode of all the motor pins
    motors.set_mode(motorPin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
for motorPin in motorDirectionPins:
    motors.set_mode(motorPin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
for motorPin in motorEnablePins:
    motors.set_mode(motorPin, pigpio.OUTPUT)

motors.wave_clear()

packages = [0, 0, 0, 0]

for motor in motorNumbers:              # iterates through each motor
    pulses = []
    for i in range(numberOfSteps[motor]):      # This generates a certain number of steps equally spaced in the cycletime
        pulses.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<motorStepPins[motor], 0, int(pulseWidth / 2)))
        pulses.append(pigpio.pulse(0, 1<<motorStepPins[motor], int(((cycleTime*1000/numberOfSteps[motor])-pulseWidth)/2)))

    motors.wave_add_generic(pulses)
        
    packages[motor] = motors.wave_create()

for motor in motorNumbers:
    motors.write(motorDirectionPins[motor], 1)
    motors.wave_send_once(packages[motor])
```

[image: Trace from the scope]

Here we can see that after each successive motor.wave_send_once it cancelled the squarewave that had been started on the other pin.

```
import pigpio

motorStepPins = (18, 23, 24, 25)        # These are the GPIO addresses for the motor wires
motorDirectionPins = (4, 17, 27, 22)
motorEnablePins = (5, 6, 13, 26)

numberOfSteps = (100, 50, 20, 10)       # This is the number of steps that each motor will advance
motorNumbers = (0, 1, 2, 3)             

pulseWidth = 100                        # The pulsewidth in microseconds
cycleTime = 20                          # time that the number of steps needs to be completed in

motor1 = pigpio.pi()                    # This initiates pigpio
motor2 = pigpio.pi()
motor3 = pigpio.pi()
motor4 = pigpio.pi()
motors = [motor1, motor2, motor3, motor4]
for motorPin in enumerate(motorStepPins):          # defines the mode of all the motor pins
    motors[motorPin[0]].set_mode(motorPin[1], pigpio.OUTPUT)
for motorPin in enumerate(motorDirectionPins):          # defines the mode of all the motor pins
    motors[motorPin[0]].set_mode(motorPin[1], pigpio.OUTPUT)
for motorPin in enumerate(motorEnablePins):          # defines the mode of all the motor pins
    motors[motorPin[0]].set_mode(motorPin[1], pigpio.OUTPUT)

for motor in motors:
    motor.wave_clear()

for motor in enumerate(motors):              # iterates through each motor
    pulses = []
    for i in range(numberOfSteps[motor[0]]):      # This generates a certain number of steps equally spaced in the cycletime
        pulses.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<motorStepPins[motor[0]], 0, int(pulseWidth / 2)))
        pulses.append(pigpio.pulse(0, 1<<motorStepPins[motor[0]], int(((cycleTime*1000/numberOfSteps[motor[0]])-pulseWidth)/2)))

motor[1].wave_add_generic(pulses)
        
package = motor[1].wave_create()

motor[1].wave_send_once(package)
```

[image: This is a trace from the second program]

Here we can see that despite each motor (GPIO Channel) being on a different instance of pigpio.pi() the squarewaves were stopped each time a wave_send_once was called.

I believe the increase in number of pulses being displayed is due to it taking more time between each wave_send_once being called.

I am running this on a raspberry pi 3 and python 3.7.3 32-bit.

Any help would be great as I have been stuck on this for a while.

**EDIT with the answer:**

Joan's answer was extremely helpful and with their input I produced this (probably incredibly inefficient) working program:

```
import pigpio
import numpy as np

motorStepPins = (18, 23, 24, 25)        # These are the GPIO addresses for the motor wires
motorDirectionPins = (4, 17, 27, 22)
motorEnablePins = (5, 6, 13, 26)

numberOfSteps = (3, 5, 7, 11)           # This is the number of steps that each motor will advance
motorNumbers = (0, 1, 2, 3)             

pulseWidth = 100                        # The pulsewidth in microseconds
cycleTime = 20                          # time that the number of steps needs to be completed in

motors = pigpio.pi()                    # This initiates pigpio
for motorPin in motorStepPins:          # defines the mode of all the motor pins
    motors.set_mode(motorPin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
for motorPin in motorDirectionPins:
    motors.set_mode(motorPin, pigpio.OUTPUT)
for motorPin in motorEnablePins:
    motors.set_mode(motorPin, pigpio.OUTPUT)

motors.wave_clear()


toggleDataType = [('name', int), ('state', int), ('time', float)]   # This is the data frmat for each toggle event
toggles = []

for motor in motorNumbers:                              # iterates through each motor
    for toggle in range(numberOfSteps[motor]):          # for each pulse it creates a toggle high and a toggle low event
        toggles.append((motor, 1, (toggle * 1000 * cycleTime / numberOfSteps[motor])))
        toggles.append((motor, 0, (toggle * 1000 * cycleTime / numberOfSteps[motor] + pulseWidth)))

toggles = np.array(toggles, dtype = toggleDataType)
toggles = np.sort(toggles, order = 'time')              # Here we have converted to a numpy array in oder to sort the list by time
toggles = toggles.tolist()


pulses = []
for event in enumerate(toggles):        # This generates a certain number of steps equally spaced in the cycletime
    if (event[0]==len(toggles)-1):      # This handles the last event not having a period (I don't think entirely necesary but looks nice at least)
        if event[1][1]:
            pulses.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<motorStepPins[event[1][0]], 0, int((cycleTime * 1000 - event[1][2]) / 2)))
        else:
            pulses.append(pigpio.pulse(0, 1<<motorStepPins[event[1][0]], int((cycleTime * 1000 - event[1][2]) / 2)))
    else:
        if event[1][1]:
            pulses.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<motorStepPins[event[1][0]], 0, int((toggles[event[0]+1][2] - event[1][2]) / 2)))
        else:
            pulses.append(pigpio.pulse(0, 1<<motorStepPins[event[1][0]], int((toggles[event[0]+1][2] - event[1][2]) / 2)))

motors.wave_add_generic(pulses)
    
package = motors.wave_create()

motors.wave_send_once(package)
```

[image: What I wanted all along]

and that is the image I wanted all along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time doubling is probably a bug which seems to happen on some Pis.  No one has found the root cause (as far as I know).

As far as waves are concerned only one can be running at a time.  You will need to merge all the stepper GPIO changes into one wave and send that.  You will have to construct a few milliseconds worth of pulses in each wave.  Send that and construct a new wave as it is being sent.  It is not simple.

Comment: Thank you very much for extremely quick response! I believe what you are saying is to put all of the pulses for each GPIO into a single waveform and then send that waveform off. I see how this can work and will try it out.

Comment: Just wanting to say thank you for providing a correct answer very quickly, I have updated the question with the code that I ended up producing that solved the issue. Couldn't have done it without your help!